# passing data to higher level projects from a low level project in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, events, asp.net-web-api, delegates

I have four (4) class libraries in c#. Three (3) (InitiatorModule, TransactorModule, LoggerModule) of which are higher level and one (1) (PublisherModule) is a lower level. All the three higher level projects have project reference to the lower level project (PublisherModule) and no reference to each other. What i want is that, the InitiatorModule initiates a transaction and sends it to PublisherModule. PublisherModule then adds some extra information then publishes the message to TransactorModule and LoggerModule of which the PublisherModule is not aware of since they are higher level class libraries. Is there a way to do this using events or delegates or any other way?

**Here is my code**

> InitiatorModule

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Models;
using Publisher;

namespace Initiator.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InitializeTransaction : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<InitializeTransaction> _logger;
        private readonly HandleIncoming _handleIncoming;

        public InitializeTransaction(ILogger<InitializeTransaction> logger, HandleIncoming handleIncoming)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _handleIncoming = handleIncoming;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] TransactionDetails transactionDetails)
        {
            _handleIncoming.Publish(transactionDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

> PublisherModule

```
using Models;
using System;

namespace Publisher
{
    public class HandleIncoming
    {
        public event TransactionHandler OutBoundTransaction;

        public void Publish(TransactionDetails transactionDetails)
        {
            transactionDetails.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
            OutBoundTransaction(transactionDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

> TransactorModule

```
using Models;
using Publisher;
using System;

namespace Transactor
{
    public class TransactionExecutor
    {
        private readonly HandleIncoming handleIncoming = new HandleIncoming();

        public TransactionExecutor()
        {
            handleIncoming.OutBoundTransaction += OnOutBoundTransaction;
        }

        public void OnOutBoundTransaction(TransactionDetails transactionDetails)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Send Amount: {transactionDetails.Amount} to Username: {transactionDetails.Recipient} \nDate: {transactionDetails.Date}");
        }
    }
}
```

> LoggerModule

```
using Models;
using Publisher;
using System;

namespace MyLogger
{
    public class TransactionLogger
    {
        private readonly HandleIncoming handleIncoming = new HandleIncoming();

        public TransactionLogger()
        {
            handleIncoming.OutBoundTransaction += OnOutBoundTransaction;
        }

        public void OnOutBoundTransaction(TransactionDetails transactionDetails)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Username: {transactionDetails.Name} \nAmount: {transactionDetails.Amount} \nDate: {transactionDetails.Date}");
        }
    }
}
```

> Delegate signature

```
namespace Models
{
    public delegate void TransactionHandler(TransactionDetails transactionDetails);
}
```

> Model

```
using System;

namespace Models
{
    public class TransactionDetails
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public string Recipient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Please note each module represent a different project**

Comment: Are you looking for the pub-sub or event bus design patterns?

Comment: *Is there a way to do this...?* - yes. Please show us some example code representing what you have and ask a more targeted question..

Comment: The trivial solution would be to have PublisherModule expose an event. Any reason this is not suitable? Or do you just want to know how events are used?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes, anything that solves my problem.

Comment: Thanx @CaiusJard i have added my sample code

Comment: @JonasH i have added sample code. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: The "high-level" classes have to share one single "Publisher" instance. I the moment each creates its own, so they cannot communicate. You could e.g. pass the Publisher instance via the constructor.

Comment: @KlausGütter the issue with that is the PublisherModule does not have reference to higher level modules hence can't know about the constructor of classes in these higher level projects

Comment: The PublisherModule does not need a reference to the other modules. You just have to pass the PublisherModule instance to the construtors of the high-level classes, as you already did with InitiatorModule. If you already use dependency injection, just register your PublisherModule instance as singleton.

Comment: One more thing to consider: depending on the intended lifetime of the objects, you may need a mechanism to unsubscribe the objects from the event.

Comment: @KlausGütter okay okay i understand now, i get your point. Let me try implementing that